# How to avoid two embedded cycles in linq query C#

Tags: c#, linq

```
var listOfIds = new List<string>(); 
var allItems = IEnumerable<Info>();

foreach (var id in collectionIds)
{
    listOfIds.AddRange(allItems
             .Where(p => p.Data.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Key == "myId").Value == id)
             .Select(x => x.Id));
}
```

I would like to avoid using `AddRange` but use only `Add` in this case and maybe use only `FirstOrDefault` in the place of where to avoid the last `Select` case.

Is this possible and if yes how?

Comment: You probably want to use `Contains` here, but I'm a little suspicious that your code doesn't do what you are hoping it does. The `Data.FirstOrDefault(...)` is unusual.

Comment: @DavidG I am more concern of the loop that query an `IEnumerable` many times while the list of very likely static at that point.

Comment: @Franck Well a `Contains` could solve that so it's not really a problem.

Comment: The code is working perfectly now , but has too many cycles in it. I hope it can be done better but do not know how to avoid them.

Comment: If it is working perfectly, then you should at least be using `First`, not `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Okay. If you have better decision , please provide me with example. Thanks.

Comment: So what happens if the second item in `p.Data` contains a matching value?

Comment: We should add each item that has the same id in the list.

Comment: So your code doesn't give you what you want then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your original code is giving you the correct data, specifically you are OK with:

1. Only concerned that the *first* item in `p.Data` contains a matching value and;
2. `p.Data` will always contains at least a single element.

Then this code will give you the same output:

```
var listOfIds = allItems
    .Where(p => collectionIds.Contains(p.Data.First(m => m.Key == "myId").Value))
    .ToList();
```

However, if you really do care that any value in `p.Data` matches, then this would be more appropriate:

```
var listOfIds = allItems
    .Where(p => p.Data.Any(m => m.Key == "myId" && 
                                collectionIds.Contains(m.Value)))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this approach:

```
var listOfIds = new List<string>(); 
var allItems = IEnumerable<Info>();

var groupedAllItems = allItems.GroupBy(x => x.Data.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Key == "myId")?.Value ?? "MyIdNotFound");

//collectionIds should be of type HashSet<string> for the contains to be fast
listOfIds.AddRange(groupedAllItems.Where(x => collectionIds.Contains(x.Key)).SelectMany(x => x));
```